# What happen when we write empty copy constructor in derived class?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int );
};

A::A(int arg) {
    i = arg;
    cout << "A's Constructor called: Value of i: " << i << endl;
}

// Class B is derived from A
class B: A {
public:
    B(int );
    B(const B& ref)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor get called"<<endl;
    }
};

B::B(int x):A(x) { //Initializer list must be used
    cout << "B's Constructor called";
}

int main() {
    B obj(10);
    return 0;
}
output:
prog.cpp: In copy constructor ‘B::B(const B&)’:
prog.cpp:20:2: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
  {
  ^
prog.cpp:10:1: note: candidate: A::A(int)
 A::A(int arg) {
 ^
prog.cpp:10:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I got above error when I added copy constructor. When I remove copy constructor error is resolved.
Can anybody explain me why I am getting error with copy constructor and even not creating object using copy constructor?

Comment: You can imagine that `B(const B& ref) {...}` is actually `B(const B& ref) : A() {...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you don't use the copy constructor of `B` it still has to be valid.

Currently it does not invoke any constructor from `A`, so then it will default to contructing the base class with the default constructor.

Since there is no default constructor, you get an error.

Comment: Thanks for answer but as per comment "currently it doesn't invoke any constructor from A" but B::B(int x):A(x)  is calling A's parameterized constructor.So object is getting created.If I remove copy constructor from class B then there is no error. Is compiler is creating copy constructor in B?

Comment: @Ocean11 Yes, the `B::B(int)` does invoke the constructor `A:A(int)`. What I meant is that `B(const B&)` does not explicitly invoke any constructor from `A`, which means that it will implicitly invoke the default constructor from `A`. But no default constructor exists. As the comment on your question above states, `B(const B&)` is equivalent to `B(const B&) : A()`, and since `A()` is not valid (you have given the class another constructor, so no default constructor will be generated by the compiler) it gives an error.

Comment: Thanks @Super. Now I am cleared.It was good explanation.Just another question, from where B(const B&) will be called. I mean I am calling B's parameterized constructor so from inside main() how B(const B&) is invoked. Is compiler is invoking?

Comment: @Ocean11 No, it's not invoked at all. But as my answer says it does not matter if you invoke it or not. It still has to be valid, which it is not. So it still generates a compile time error.

Comment: :Thanks a lot Now fully clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined an explicit empty copy constructor but it doesn't have any [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

By default, compiler will be calling `A::A()` in the member initialization list.

```
B(const B& ref): A()
{
    std::cout << "copy constructor get called" << std::endl;
}
```

Since, there is no default constructor of `A` which doesn't take any argument. The compiler is throwing an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
```